# Displaying MySQL data on HTML page in Django - data not displaying

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views, mariadb

I am totally new to Django and I'm having a problem displaying data from a MariaDB MySQL database on a HTML page.

I have a legacy database called `Vision` which has a table within it called `SensorResult`. I have added this database to the `settings.py` file and made a routings folder with a `router_db.py` file to tell the app when to use the `Vision` database.

From this, I ran the following command:

> `python manage.py inspectdb --database=Vision`

This returned a printout of each table within the database and all columns. I then used this to create a standard `models.py` file using this information as shown below:

```
from django.db import models

class Sensorresult(models.Model):
    sensorresult = models.AutoField(db_column='SensorResult', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sensorid = models.IntegerField(db_column='SensorID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    visionid = models.IntegerField(db_column='VisionID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    userinputid = models.IntegerField(db_column='UserInputID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    value = models.FloatField(db_column='Value')  # Field name made lowercase.
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='TimeStamp')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'SensorResult'
```

From this, I used makemigrations and migrate commands to submit this model. Now I can open the Django Shell and query the database and get a response, which makes me think that the `models.py`, `settings.py` and `db_routings.py` files are all working correctly (please tell me if this is not the case)? An example of the shell commands and printout response I get is as follows:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from authenticate.models import Sensorresult
>>> qs = Sensorresult.objects.using('Vision').get(sensorresult="1")
>>> qs.value
556746.0
```

From this I have created the following `views.py` file, which has an identical SQL command as that used in the shell:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .models import Sensorresult

def db(request):
    qs = Sensorresult.objects.using('Vision').get(sensorresult='1')
    return render(request, 'authenticate/instruments.html',{'qs':qs})
```

and then an `instruments.html` which is as follows:

```
<div class="overviewcard">
<div class="overviewcard__icon">Engine</div>
<div class="overviewcard__info">{{qs.value}}</div>
```

However for some reason I dont get any data displaying, just blank. I also have a `URLs.py` page which is as follows:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from . import models

#used for routing within the app
#use the below format to add further pages 

urlpatterns = [
   path('instruments/', views.instruments, name="instruments"),
   path('instruments/',views.db, name='db'),

  ]
```

I've been through loads of online tutorials and YouTube videos; however, none have worked so far. If anyone has any suggestions as to what is going wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use unique paths for your url patterns or you will get conflicts, the first path is always matching so your `db` view is never called.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('instruments/', views.db, name='db'),
    path('instruments/foo/', views.instruments, name="instruments"),
]
```

The url dispatcher iterates over your urlpatterns in order and returns the first one that matches the incoming path, if you have two patterns that could match the path then the first one will always be used

Comment: Hi Iain, many thanks for your suggestion. I have changed the URL's and the information is now showing on instruments/db webpage. Do you know if there is anyway to have this showing just on the instruments/ webpage. Thanks for your help in fixing this

Comment: @EdwardBlissitt Updated the answer, the urlpatterns should now serve the `db` view at `instruments/`

Comment: Hi Iain, Thanks for your reply, Unfortunately the new code doesnt work, I think this is because of the login credentials I have to the instruments page. I will just change the instruments button on other pages to instruments/db as you suggested before as that seems to be working perfectly. Many thanks

Comment: Hi Iain, thanks for your comments, it is all working properly now. I want this data to  update automatically without refreshing the web page, do you know how I could do this? Many thanks for your help